# /dev/sda5: recovering journal

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

The boot is not progressing and GRUB is also not opening. I have tried to open GRUB but It won’t.

[image: boot screen]

Answer (score 1):

You don't give much information, but you could try booting to a bootable Ubuntu USB, or CD, and then trying to perform the "fsck" manually from within there, in case it's prompting for input.